# Ist das Deutsche noch in der Lage oder bereit, neue Wörter mithilfe von Präfixen oder Suffixen zu schaffen?

Tags: word-formation

Ich beobachte, dass die meisten neue Wörter in der deutschen Sprache entweder unverändert übernommene Fremdwörter aus dem Englischen (*Grow Bag*), Lehnausdrücke (*viral gehen*) oder einfache Komposita aus bestehenden Substantiven sind (*Energiewende*). Aber werden überhaupt noch Wörter mit Affixen gebildet? Wie etwa:

- Umleitung
- Abstand
- Abbau
- Unterhalt
- Leidenschaft
- kostbar

Gibt es neuere Beispiele?

Comment: Ich würde ja eher vermuten, dass Wortbildungen ohne Fremdwortanteil so schnell eingängig werden, dass niemanden auffält, dass sie neu sind. Biete: *unkaputtbar*, *unvermittelbar*, *endlagern*. Behördendeutsch ist vermutlich ein unendlicher Quell solcher Neologismen.

Comment: Zur generellen Fähigkeit der Sprache, neue Wörter zu erfinden, siehe http://www.wortwarte.de (kurz: ungebrochene Kreativität)

Answer (score 5):

Das Deutsche ist durchaus in der Lage, neue Wörter auch mit Präfixen zu schaffen. Suffixe haben in der Regel eher eine grammatikalische Funktion und lassen sich fast immer nach den selben Regeln einsetzen, sodass es niemanden überrascht, wenn aus dem neuen Verb *riestern* das Substantiv *Riesterei* wird.

Eine Quelle für solche Neubildungen ist, wie Janka erwähnt, das Behördendeutsch – diese finden aber selten den Weg in die Allgemeinsprache. Eine andere typische Quelle ist in meinen Augen die Jugendsprache, aus der es Begriffe auch durchaus in die allgemeine Umgangssprache schaffen. Das folgende [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=abzocken%2Babgezockt%2Czocken%2Bgezockt%2Cverzocken%2Bverzockt&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28abzocken%20%2B%20abgezockt%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28zocken%20%2B%20gezockt%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28verzocken%20%2B%20verzockt%29%3B%2Cc0) verdeutlicht, dass *zocken* im Deutschen zwar immer wieder verwendet wurde, die Ableitungen *abzocken* und *verzocken* jedoch erst in der zweiten Hälfte des letzten Jahrhunderts aufkamen; *abzocken* scheint sogar erst in den Neunzigern entstanden zu sein:

[image: Ngram für abzocken, zocken und verzocken]

Ohne Quellen um das zu belegen würde ich diese Neubildungen ursprünglich der Jugendsprache zuordnen.

Definitiv jugendsprachlich ist das Wort *abhartzen,* das erst nach den Hartz-Gesetzen in diesem Jahrtausend entstanden sein kann. Im Jahr 2015 wurde das Verb *rumoxidieren* mit dem dritten Platz als [Jugendwort des Jahres](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jugendwort_des_Jahres_%28Deutschland%29) ausgezeichnet. Da die Jugendsprache oft schnelllebig ist (was gestern dufte war, ist heute schon veraltet), darf man annehmen, dass es in dieser Dekade erst entstanden sein durfte.

Comment: Bei der Klammer am Schluss musste ich lachen, sehr schön.

Comment: Das ulkige Verb *verorten* steht erst seit 2004 im Duden.

Comment: *aufhübschen*: auch 2004

Comment: Quelle aus 1990 zu _rumoxidieren_: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7zHka726S9k

Comment: @moooeeeep Interessant, vielleicht eine Erklärung für die Herkunft. Sieht für mich allerdings so aus, als würde *rumoxidieren* in dem Fall noch *rosten* bedeuten. Demnach stellt sich die Frage, wann es erstmalig in der Bedeutung *herumhängen, abchillen* eingesetzt wurde. Oh, *abchillen* ist ja auch eine Bildung mit Präfix!

Comment: Für solche Angelegenheiten ist N-Grams unschätzbar wertvoll. Ich hätte niemals gedacht, daß "verorten" erst in diesem Millenium üblich wurde. Die Antwort ist also anscheinend, daß Neubildungen sehr wohl geschehen, und zwar *so selbstverständlich, daß man sie nicht als neu wahrnimmt*.